# how to handle subchains easily in airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I want to do the following:

```
chain(
  A,
  [
    [B, C],
    D,
    E,
  ],
  F
)
```

which should result in:

```
  A >> B >> C
  A >> D
  A >> E
  C >> F
  D >> F
  E >> F
```

Is there a `chain()` function-ish method to handle any nested relationship instead of typing it out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no (depending on what version of Airflow you are using).

With Airflow 2.7, there is [a new dependency function called `chain_linear()`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html#airflow.models.baseoperator.chain_linear) which doesn't have the same constraints as `chain()` (namely requiring lists to be the same length). You could take advantage of this along with `chain()` with *slight* "duplication".

```py
from pendulum import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain, chain_linear
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator


@dag(start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None)
def fun_with_chains() -> None:
    a, b, c, d, e, f = [EmptyOperator(task_id=f"task_{i}") for i in "ABCDEF"]

    chain(a, b, c, f)
    chain_linear(a, [d, e], f)


fun_with_chains()
```

[image]

However, if you are not using 2.7 or can't upgrade yet, you can always use Task Groups (to group the tasks in the main list in your example):

```py
from pendulum import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag, task_group
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator


@dag(start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None)
def fun_with_chains() -> None:
    a, f = [EmptyOperator(task_id=f"task_{i}") for i in "AF"]

    @task_group
    def group() -> None:
        b, c, d, e = [EmptyOperator(task_id=f"task_{i}") for i in "BCDE"]
        chain(b, c)

    chain(a, group(), f)


fun_with_chains()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Is there a "dag browser" I can use for testing? Your posted DAG interface view differs a lot from mine, this is airflow UI?

Comment: This is in Airflow. Just using the Graph view that's embedded in the Grid view (since 2.6.0). I was using Airflow 2.7 in the screenshots.